# Input form from Dropdown called by Button closes when inputing something

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm currently trying to get a dropdown with a simple input field to work.

I have this piece of code in my html:

```
<li>
    <a class='dropdown-button btn' data-beloworigin="true" href='#' data-activates='dropdown2'>Teamspeak</a>
    <ul id='dropdown2' class='dropdown-content'>
        <li>
            <input id="username" type="text" class="validate">
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="ts3server://TEAMSPEAKSERVER/?port=9987">Join</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

It's working alright so far and looks like I want it to but as soon as I try to input something in the Username field the Dropdown closes. How can I stop it from closing when trying to input something?
When I click the button and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I can input somethings without problem, which I kind of don't understand.

Also, can anyone maybe give me a tip on how to get the input into the
XXX below?

```
<a href="ts3server://TEAMSPEAKSERVER/?port=9987&nickname=XXX">
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can maybe help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on input, the event is propagated to parents, which causes the dropdown close.
Use the following jQuery code to stop event propagation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#username").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

See also: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Thanks, that's what i've been looking for.